# Does the Amnesia spell affect spellcasting?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature

Simple question, i just need someone to confirm if i remember correctly: if i cast the Amnesia spell on a spellcaster, does that spellcaster lose spellcasting abilities until levelling up? Because i'm pretty sure that spellcasting is a class feature that the Amnesia spell takes care of.

Answer (score 3):

## [*Amnesia*](http://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Amnesia) removes a creature's class-gained spellcasting

A subject that fails its Will saving throw against the [*amnesia*](http://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Amnesia) spell [instantaneously](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Duration) "loses all class abilities… gained before being affected by *amnesia*." Thus, a creature that gains from its class the ability to cast spells would, in fact, lose that ability.

And the *amnesia* spell's long-term effect is probably worse than you remember:

> [When the subject] gains a character level while suffering from amnesia, it can use any abilities gained by that class level normally[, but i]f the class level it gained was from a class in which it already has levels, it gains the abilities of a 1st-level character of that class, even though it is technically of a higher level in that class.

The *amnesia* spell's effect can only be removed by effects like *heal*, *limited wish*, *miracle*, *psychic surgery*, or *wish*.

That such a spell appears in the [*Villain' Codex*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9oo7?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Villain-Codex) should come as no surprise, however the fact that *amnesia* is only a 4th-level spell may.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, amnesia "erase" the possibility for a spellcaster to cast a spell...and actually amnesia spell "erase" everything a character knows, no matter what class the character is.

> [Amnesia](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/amnesia/)
>
> [...] The target can still speak and read any languages it knows and perform basic tasks, but it **loses all class abilities, feats, and skill ranks** gained before being affected by amnesia. **It retains its base attack bonus, saving throws bonuses, Combat Maneuver Bonus, Combat Maneuver Defense, total experience points, Hit Dice, and hit points.** If the target gains a character level while suffering from amnesia, it can use any abilities gained by that class level normally. If the class level it gained was from a class in which it already has levels, it gains the abilities of a 1st-level character of that class, even though it is technically of a higher level in that class.
>
> [...] **Amnesia can be removed only by heal, limited wish, miracle, psychic surgery, or wish.**

I don't know why you want to use Amnesia and, if you are the GM, it's ok. If you are a player, instead, my suggestion is to talk with your GM...personally i will never allow such a spell for a player's character since it can be easily abused (and keep in mind it come from a source called "Villain codex").

Comment: I disagree with "if you are the GM, it's ok". Using this spell on your players is a dick move, and while it may be appropriate in certain situations, you should certainly consider using it carefully before you do use it.

Comment: I'm agree with you, it is a dick move...in the same way it is a dick move to cast dominate person on PCs and many other spells or manouver (like sunder, for example). The point is: if you are the GM it is supposed you are managing the game. Don't use death spells or domination spells without reason or without giving your players a way to recover from that.

Comment: Then allow me to ask: what do you think the appropriate situations are?

Comment: I think every GM can write a book to answer your question and every book will be more or less different from the other. Anyway I will say that if you are the GM YOU need to find your reason and situation to go all inn at your table (since failing a death spell or amnesia or feeblemind oftern means a lot of troubles for players). You are not just a dice reader; you are managing the story that often you made up yourself. You want scare them? Use something to scare them (in the same way you use music). - Continue

Comment: The description "his voice stops from murmuring unholy words when his finger raise and point at you and than a red dark beam fly in the air and...in less then a second...hit you in the chest, right above the heart. " Now ask a fortitude check. Why all this fluff? Because you want this moment, this spell, is not a generic moment in a generic fight. You, as everyone, have limited time at your table because work, life, wife, etc etc. The "rule" here for me is: is not important if they died or if my boss died. They had fun? if the answer is yes, you did good.